# regenerating session id

Tags: php, security, session

I am thinking of using this code on every page to reduce the possibility of session hijacking. By renewing the session_id on every request

```
if(!empty($_session)){ 
   session_start(); 
}
```

Another way to achieve so would be to do this:

```
if(!empty($_session)){ 
  session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```

However, I heard criticisms of that function that say that if the page is refreshed too fast for some reason, the session id becomes invalid.

Another way to use the session id is to have more control over how a session is generated.

There are other ways to achieve so.. Whats the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of generating session IDs,why don't you encrypt and use the already generated one.It can be used and destroyed when the intended action is complete.

Comment: The best case is to regenerate the id only ones.at the point of entry(login) only.

Comment: how do I do that? how do I get the session id.. I have an encrypting function that works, and I could decrypt it. I am not concerned about speed..Is this the way to do it: session_id($newSession); and then when I decrypt it, how do I save the old session id..? in the database?

Comment: session_start();session_regenerate_id(true);  $_SESSION['user_session']=session_id();  $user_session=$_SESSION['user_session'];//Try pass $user_session for encryption.You can echo it first for test

Comment: After use remember to unset the session unset($_SESSION);You might also consider destroying it if you don't need it any more. session_destroy();

Comment: okay, I got it, I need to put the session id into the database, then I need to encrypt the session id, and dycrypt it when I want to compare it with the value of the database. Is that the way to do it?

Comment: Yes can do that and alternatively you can just hold the session in the browser cookies as they are. Check this site it might be of great help http://www.zimuel.it/en/encrypt-php-session-data/

Answer (score 28):

Calling `session_regenerate_id` on every page is an unnescessary overhead.

You should only be calling it at the point of login or any time you re-authorize a user.

If you want additionally you could store the last regenerated time in a session and then call `session_regenerate_id` after say 30 minutes, but there's definetly no need for this to be done on every page.

Answer (score 7):

I **had problems indeed** (on page refresh or inside ajax requests), using  `session_regenerate_id(true);` on each request.

But not with `session_regenerate_id();`

So, according to

> Renew the Session ID After Any Privilege Level Change
>   https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Renew_the_Session_ID_After_Any_Privilege_Level_Change
>
> Regenerate SID on each request
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation#Regenerate_SID_on_each_request

i use

- `session_regenerate_id();` on each request
- `session_regenerate_id(true);` on login, logout etc (any privilege level change)

Comment: Isn't `session_regenerate_id(FALSE)` litter the server with session files?

Answer (score 3):

Best practise is to use SSL (and apply the usual defences against other security attack vectors such as XSS and SQL injection). Cycling session ids is just begging for race conditions.

Comment: SSL won't protect you from harvested cookies through, say, XSS.

Comment: "I am familiar with ssl, but I dont want to buy it from my webhost

Comment: @Dmitry — Cheap or secure, pick one.

Comment: well, I am developing a political forum, I will go for the cheap option, why do I care?

Answer (score 1):

> However, I heard criticisms of that function that say that if the page is refreshed too fast for some reason, the session id becomes invalid.

Well, I guess you have to try it out to confirm that, but I don't think you'll ever experience that problem.

Anyway, regenerating the session for every pageload doesn't secure you completely from session hijacking and uses resources that are better spent somewhere else. A better place to start would be looking at SSL. Encrypting the data between the client and the webserver is more secure.

I personally only regenerate a session id when a user logs in AND when a user logs out of my applications.

Comment: why to regenerate the session whenever the user logs into the the webpage

Comment: I like the idea that whenever my user enters or leaves something I restricted to others, they start a new session. I have no technical arguments as to why.

Comment: It hasn't been an issue for me - I can't deny it can happen, as many people warns about it, but I havent experinced it (yet).